# Upload photos to Flickr With API Flickr Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried upload photo to flickr with the API Python but I get this error:

> err code="100" msg="Invalid API Key (Key has invalid format)"

I'm supposed Flickr authenticated because simpler ones I call functions that also require authentication as flickr.photos.getInfo,  flickr.photos.getPerms or flickr.photos.geo.setLocation and return results without problem.

This is my code:

```
import flickrapi
import csv
import requests

api_key = 'xxxxxxx'
api_secret = 'zzzzzzzz'
flickr = flickrapi.FlickrAPI(api_key, api_secret)
flickr.authenticate_via_browser(perms='delete')

def uploadPhoto(path_photo, title, description, tags):
    result=False;
    with open(path_photo, 'rb') as f:
        photo = {'file': f}
        try:    
            result = requests.post('https://up.flickr.com/services/upload/', data = {'photo':'photo', 'title':'title', 'description':'description', 'tags':'tags'})
            print(result.text)
        except Exception as error:
            print('Upload photo', error, '--- o --- titulo malo -> ', title)        
    return result

with open('/home/labsis06/djandoprojects/generales.csv') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
    #for row in spamreader:
    try:
        path_photo = '/home/labsis06/djandoprojects/Fotos_flickr/Phaeophytas4024/4024.55.165_C_sinuosa_000_01_600_778x820.jpg'
        title = 'C_sinuosa_000_01_600_778x820.jpg'
        description = 'Nombre Especie: Colpomenia sinuosa (Mertens ex Roth) Derbès y Solier . Descripción: Sartedemie'
        tags = 'OCHROPHYTA'+','+'Phaeophyceae'+','+'Scytosiphonaceae'+','+'Colpomenia'
        print("Ingresando fotos: result: "+str(uploadPhoto(path_photo, title, description, tags)))
    except Exception as error:
        print('Abiendo csv', error)
```

I have a group of pictures (approximately 3000 pictures) and I want to upload a csv file, but to prove what I'm doing with a static value.

Any idea what is the problem?

Appreciate your help.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you are using the API from https://stuvel.eu/flickrapi?

If so, the docs say the API key and secret need to be a unicode string (https://stuvel.eu/flickrapi-doc/2-calling.html), so you'll need to prefix your literals with a 'u'.

i.e.

```
api_key = u'xxxxxxx'
api_secret = u'xxxxxxx'
```

Comment: Hi Steve , I had tested well and has the same error :(

Answer (score 0):

If you are using https://stuvel.eu/flickrapi then you should be using [flickr.upload](https://stuvel.eu/flickrapi-doc/4-uploading.html).

If not then need to sign the call which uploads the photo, and I can't see that you actually upload the photo data as you are quoting photo here:

```
    result = requests.post('https://up.flickr.com/services/upload/', data = {'photo':'photo', 'title':'title', 'description':'description', 'tags':'tags'})
```

See [uploader.py](https://github.com/ept/uploadr.py/blob/master/uploadr/uploadr.py#L360) for a python example and the [Flickr documentation](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/upload.api.html).